# Can the display casing from a 13" MBP be used as a replacement on a 13" Aluminum Unibody?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

Can the [display casing for a 13" MacBook Pro](http://www.ifixit.com/MacBook-Parts/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Mid-2009-Mid-2010-Display-Assembly/IF163-001#relatedQuestions) be used in lieu of the [corresponding part for a 13" Aluminum Unibody MacBook?](http://www.ifixit.com/MacBook-Parts/MacBook-Unibody-Model-No-A1278-Display-Assembly/IF160-002)?

Both screens have identical specifications and appear to have the internal connectors. Also, with the new aluminum construction heralding being a new design, it's doubtful that Apple made major changes to the frame or significantly modified the internals when they refreshed the old aluminum unibody MacBook.

That being said, I don't have access to either of these screens, and a fairly innocuous difference (say a difference of an inch on one of the internal cables) could render them incompatible. Another opinion or, better yet, first-hand experience, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - the cable routing for the pro comes to the left side and the MacBook on the right. Check fixit.com for the details - it matters if you have a 2009/2010/2011 MacBook pro - each part is slightly different.

Comment: Also - the clutch alignment isn't perfect, the embedded airport card might not fit when moving it over. See http://guide-images.ifixit.net/igi/KX4fAOE6kkiQnPIE.medium vs http://guide-images.ifixit.net/igi/lFHkbAF31XEwv2bK.medium